# Magento 2 : Add Custom Field on Checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address, custom-field

I need to add `text field` below shipping address checkout page and save content in `sales_order` table in database.

I tried following http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html 
but it simply doesn't work.

I searched many sites with similar problems but no one solved this. 
Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Any solution for this query ?